# Passing flags to bash script with case statement - only first flag is set

Tags: bash, shell-script

This might be an obvious error but I'm just not seeing it.
I have a case statement which is supposed to enable passing arguments to a script (ex: `script.sh --verbose --all`).

For some reason, this specific function does not work correctly - it only works on whichever flag I pass first:

```bsh
#Pass arguments to the script
flags()
{
    while test $# -gt 0
    do
        case "$1" in
        (-v|--verbose)
            shift
            export VERBOSE="1"
            shift;;
        (-vv|--extra-verbose)
            shift
            export VERBOSE="1"
            export EXTRA_VERBOSE="1"
            shift;;
        (-a|--all)
            shift
            export ALL="1"
            shift;;
        (-h|--help)
            usage;;
        (*) usage;;
        esac
    done
}
flags "$@"
echo "Verbose: $VERBOSE, Extra Verbose: $EXTRA_VERBOSE, All: $ALL"
```

So in this case, if I pass `-v -a`, the script will only set the `$VERBOSE` variable. If I pass `-a -v`, the script will only set the `$ALL` variable.

I have quite a few scripts using this structure which do not exhibit this.

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me figure out what is it I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you `shift` twice?

Comment: The intention was to move past the next flag to the next argumet. Should I remove one of the `shift`s?

Comment: Each `shift` removes one value from the start of the list

Comment: @PGEL: if you pass `-v -a`, `$1` is `-v` and `$2` is `-a`. After a `shift`, `$1` is `-a`. After the second `shift`, `$#` is 0.

Comment: You don't need to `export` every variable.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your helpful input. I had something else entirely in mind. I'll try without the exports as well - it's a paranoid habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many `shift`.
It should be done just once, after you processed an argument, you shift to a next one.

```
#!/bin/sh
#Pass arguments to the script
flags()
{
    while test $# -gt 0
    do
        case "$1" in
        -v|--verbose)
            export VERBOSE="1"
            ;;
        -vv|--extra-verbose)
            export VERBOSE="1"
            export EXTRA_VERBOSE="1"
            ;;
        -a|--all)
            export ALL="1"
            ;;
        -h|--help)
            usage;;
        *) usage;;
        esac

        # and here we shift to the next argument 
        shift
    done
}
flags "$@"
echo "Verbose: $VERBOSE, Extra Verbose: $EXTRA_VERBOSE, All: $ALL"
```